# EventLog.EntryWritten event handles events from the past

Tags: c#, .net, windows, events

I got this issue on Windows Server 2008 R2.

I have a custom application log, lets name it "MyCustomLog", this event log receives hundreds of entries a minute. Some of them are warnings or errors. I have created simple console app to print events:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        EventLog eventLog = new EventLog("MyCustomLog", Environment.MachineName);
        eventLog.EntryWritten += new EntryWrittenEventHandler(OnEntryWritten);
        eventLog.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void OnEntryWritten(object sender, EntryWrittenEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Entry.EntryType == EventLogEntryType.Error
            || e.Entry.EntryType == EventLogEntryType.Warning)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Now Date:" + DateTime.Now);
            Console.WriteLine("Received:" + e.Entry.TimeWritten);
            Console.WriteLine(e.Entry.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

From time to time `EntryWritten` handles events from the past, I mean events from previous day or so...

Why does it happens? What am I missing?

**Update:** Here is an example with application output:

```
Now Date:2013-10-02 15:05:04
Received:2013-10-01 10:20:02
<Some Data>


Now Date:2013-10-02 15:05:04
Received:2013-10-01 10:20:08
<Some Data>


Now Date:2013-10-02 15:05:04
Received:2013-10-01 10:20:49
<Some Data>


Now Date:2013-10-02 15:05:04
Received:2013-10-01 10:20:54
<Some Data>
```

Answer (score -1):

In your OnEntryWritten function, your 'e' does not actually contain the current log, but an instance of EntryWrittenEventArgs class. You have to find a way of getting the index of the current entry.. easily retrievable -> Entries[Entries.Count-1]. This will have your current log. Hope this helps.